# Using EWS Streaming to get data from exchange server

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is it possible with the `EWS Streaming` service, to read data from the server, which are created before streaming was started?

For example if a user creates an `Appointment` or edit an `Appointment` when the streaming service is not available, can i receive them later using `EWS Streaming`? Or is this a kind of *live* data transportation and if I'm not connected with the exchange service, the data gets lost.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EWS Streaming notifications just notify you that an Item has change,arrived etc if your not connected you won't get events during the outage  period what you should do is supplement what you are doing with streaming notifications with SyncFolderItems etc eg theres a sample for that here https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange/Exchange-2013-Use-55cc3b2a/view/SourceCode#content . As an adjunct I would also look at also using the PR_LOCAL_COMMIT_TIME_MAX property on a folder to tell if the underlying folder contents have been modified during any outage time see "Recovering from lost subscriptions" in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458788(v=exchg.150).aspx

Cheers
Glen